# Multiselectbox on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a multiselectbox like this one http://jsfiddle.net/bDvkQ/1038/.

I added the field "Select/Deselect All" and added the class "selectAllBox" using this code:

```
$("label[for='Items_option_1']").addClass("selctAllBox");
$("label[for='Items_option_1']").parent().addClass("selctAllBox")
```

result:

```
<li tabindex="-1" class="k-item selctAllBox" role="option" unselectable="on">
<input name="Items_option_1" type="checkbox" value="1">&nbsp;
<label class="selctAllBox" for="Items_option_1">Select/Deselect All</label>
</li>
```

[image]

I want that If I select the "Select/Deselect All" checkbox all checkboxes are deselected. I already have a function that can do that but I can't figure out how to call this function now. I tried doing it like that but nothing happens:

```
 $("label[for='Items_option_1']").parent().click(deselectSelectAll);
```

or

```
$("input[name="Items_option_1"]:checkbox").click(deselectSelectAll);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `$('input[name="Items_option_1"]').change(deselectSelectAll);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function works fine,

you can call it onClick of `selctAllBox` class.

Code is like this:

```
$(".selctAllBox").click(deselectSelectAll);
```

Comment: I tried that as well but nothing happens I really don't know what I am doing wrong